# Could someone please help me fix this code, I'm new to java

Tags: java

I have a specified array. I need to pass them all through the while loop and everytime there is a change in increasing or decreasing order, I add 1 to Totalrun. e.g. 2,3,7 are all increasing, but if the next number in the array is less than 7, then it adds 1 to the run, to start a new run. A run is a list of contiguous numbers that are either all increasing (ups) or all decreasing (downs).

```
public class run {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean prevgrad;

        int[] number = {2, 3, 7, 4, 5, 1, 12, 14, 9, 28};

        int Totalrun = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < number.length - 2; i++) {
            int prevnum = number[i];
            int currnum = number[i + 1];

            if (currnum > prevnum) {
                prevgrad = true;

                if (currnum > prevnum) {
                    if (prevgrad = true) {
                    } else {
                        Totalrun = Totalrun + 1;
                        prevgrad = false;
                        if (currnum < prevnum) {
                            if (prevgrad = false) {
                            } else {
                                Totalrun = Totalrun + 1;
                            }
                            prevgrad = false;
                            break;
                            System.out.println(Totalrun);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

error:

```
run.java:30: error: unreachable statement
                        System.out.println(Totalrun);
                        ^
1 error
```

Comment: "There is surely something wrong with my code" - indeed - you're not iterating the array (use a for-loop for that). `Number.hasNext()` should not compile...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it, here it is not for you to copy, but to learn from. From here on out, I would HIGHLY recommend you go and watch some videos or even read a good book on Java. Posting every question you have on stackoverflow doesn't help near as much as a good book on programming.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] number = {2,3,7,4,5,1,12,14,9,28}; // 1, 4, -3, 1, -4, 11, 2, -5, 1 <- These are differences from curr - prev

        int totalRun, incRun = 0, decRun = 0; // Not 1, what if theyre all increasing/decreasing? Run never goes to 1.

        for (int i = 0; i < number.length - 1; i++) {
            int prevnum = number[i];
            int currnum = number[i+1];
            int difference = currnum - prevnum;
            if (difference > 0)
                incRun++;
            else
                decRun++;
        }

        if (number[1] > number[0])
            totalRun = incRun;
        else
            totalRun = decRun;

        System.out.println("Total run: " + totalRun);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is number.length - 2?

Comment: Glad I could help, if this is the answer you were looking for or helped you the most, you should accept it (Checkmark on the left)

Comment: "You can accept this answer in 4 minutes". Will do : )

Comment: Well array indexing starts at 0. So if I have 10 elements, the index of the last element is 9. To access each element, you would have to iterate through length - 1 elements. But since were comparing the second last element with the last element, we have to consider it with n - 2. You could rewrite it but theres no point.

Comment: Another way would be 'for (int i = 0; i < number.length - 1; i++)  and then prevNumb = number[i - 1] and currNumb = number[i] but this is simply a rewording. To fully grasp this concept, I'd recommend printing out i + " " + number[i] to see how that loop works.

Comment: I have edited the code like you said. But there are still errors in the looping.

Comment: Doesn't seem like theres an error in the looping, but rather you do something wrong with the numbers.  if(prevgrad = "up"); .... Big mistake. I think you should read a book on Java or watch some tutorials. 1st off: You're over thinking it. 2. When comparing strings, we dont use =, nor ==, we use the .equals function 3. dont put a semicolon when you start a loop. it should be if (prevgrad.equals("up") { code here }

Comment: actually I changed my code, and now I'm only getting one error, could you please take a look? :)

Comment: Gave you a complete answer.

Comment: done :) by the way, what exactly is going on here?  if (number[1] > number[0])
            totalRun = incRun;
        else
            totalRun = decRun;

Comment: I had to test it in a different case... What if the beginning numbers were 7 3 2.. The differences would be -4 and -1 respectively. In this case, our 'totalRun' would be looking for all the negative differences instead. That line you mentioned helps us determine which one we need to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access an array's values in that fashion (at least not that I know of). There are multiple ways you could use, I personally would use an array `for` loop for this example.

```
prevNum = 0;
for (int currNum: Number) {
    if (prevNum > currNum) {
        prevgrad = "up";
        ... rest of the code;
    }
}
```

The reason for this is in this type of for loop, the value of `currNum` is equal to whatever the value of the array is in that iteration.

The complete code would be:

```
int prevNum = 0;
int totalRun = 0;
for (int currNum: Number) {
    if (prevNum > currNum) {
        prevgrad = "up";
    }
    else {
        totalRun++;
        prevgrad = "down";
    }
    prevNum = currNum;
}
```